# Assembly EAX register behaves oddly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm fairly new to assembly, and trying to read a value from standard input (calling the scanf function from C) and printing it back to standard output (with printf).

```
.text
readstr:    .asciz "%d"     #string used for calling scanf
printstr:   .asciz "%d\n"   #string used for calling printf

.global main

main:   movl    %esp, %ebp  #initialize base pointer
    call    inout

    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $printstr
    call    printf

    pushl   $0      #push exit code to stack
    call    exit    #exit with the exit code

inout:  pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    subl    $4, %esp
    leal    -4(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $readstr
    call    scanf

    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

The expected output would be the same number as the input, however the output is always

```
1
```

note: compiled on a 64-bit suse linux enterprise desktop, using gcc -m32 -o inout inout.s

What's going wrong here?

Comment: You are writing very incorrect assembly code, not getting the function arguments and return value right and imbalancing the stack. Use a C compiler and look at its assembly output to get this right.

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn how to use a debugger.   Then you can step through the code, examining the registers and memory locations to see if they contain what you expect them to contain at each point.  Where what you expect, and what you see, don't match, either your code is broken or your understanding is broken and you can debug either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you call `scanf()`, `%eax` contains the function's return value, which is [the number of input items assigned](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/). This in your case is always `1`, since there's always a single input item.

You need to place the value at `-4(%ebp)` into `%eax` before returning from `inout()`.